# How to use one table multiple times?

Tags: cakephp

I have a table called **flights** in which I set the *departure* and *arrival* airport. The **airports** is just another table and I want just to use the airport id in the flights table. How can I do this?, normally I can only use one id (airport_id) how can I use the second one? something like airport_id_2 ?..

My Flight model looks like this:

```
class Flight extends AppModel{
    public $hasOne = "Airport";
}
```

Or should I do this manually by using joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use two fields:

```
arrival_airport_id

departure_airport_id
```

and in your Model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    "DepartureAirport" => array(
        'className' => 'Airport',
        'foreignKey' => 'departure_airport_id'
    ),
    "ArrivalAirport" => array(
         'className' => 'Airport',
         'foreignKey' => 'arrival_airport_id'
    )
)
```

PS: I think the right relationships is belongsTo and not HasOne because one airport can be related to many flights

Comment: thanks :) yes you are right, it should be $belongsTo. I am just starting out with cake and some things are a little bit confusing.